# Is there a dotnet function that creates a blank razor page?

Tags: c#, .net, razor

.NET provides a scaffold to create a ASP.NET Core Web App with Razor pages, however, I was looking if there was a way to get those pages to become blank instead of having the default Microsoft pages along with the weather code that is in the package. I wanted to learn the ASP.NET scaffold but the extra code was confusing me.

Comment: If you can find the html page that creates the weather you can try removing that code

Comment: Helpful very yes